# calling an event handler inside another event handler in the same class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following event handlers:

```
protected void DataList1_UpdateCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
```

and

```
protected void DataList2_UpdateCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
```

How can I call `DataList2_UpdateCommand` inside `DataList1_UpdateCommand`.

without having to paste all of the code in  `DataList2_UpdateCommand` into `DataList1_UpdateCommand`?

Comment: yes, event handler is a method like any other, you can call it by name

Comment: Those are event handlers, not events.  Big difference.

Comment: set the source as datalist 2, fill the DataListCommandEventArgs the way you want and call the other method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, if you are using the same arguments, then you can just call it like any other method.*

```
DataList2_UpdateCommand(source, e);
```

If you want to create a new event arg:

```
DataList2_UpdateCommand(source, new DataListCommandEventArgs(e.Item, e.CommandSource, e.CommandArgument);
```

*Given your code example at least...which is an event handler, not an event. And, an event handler is just a regular method.

Comment: i just realized that i will need to use a different argument. do you have any ideas on how i can initialize a new argument "f", so i am able to do DataList2_UpdateCommand(source, f);

Comment: sorry i dont understand new DataListCommandEventArgs(..)... plz can you edit your answer with the initialization of the new argument? thanks

Comment: You initialize it like any other constructor. Pass in the arguments you want in the new object and voila....new object.

Comment: i tried putting : new DataListCommandEventArgs(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs f); ontop, however i get an error, saying "}" expected. i know ive got some kind of syntax wrong. new to ASP.net